# Post push notification to C2DM (android) using Django

Tags: android, django, push-notification

I found how to send push notification to Android device using Django [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033824/pushing-data-from-django-app-to-android-app) ([here is the code](https://github.com/patrickbaumann/c2dmprototype/blob/master/pushprototypedjango/push/views.py#L93)).

So adopted that and my code looks like this:

```
def sendAndroidPushNotification(registration_id, collapse_key, a, b) :
    try:
        auth = getNewAndroidAuthorizationToken() # this works I'm fetching new token so this is up to date (its length is 267 characters)
        push_request = urllib2.Request("https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send")

        data = urllib.urlencode({'data.testA'     : a,
                                 'data.testB'     : b,
                                 'collapse_key'   : collapse_key,
                                 'registration_id': registration_id
                                 })
        push_request.add_data( data )
        push_request.add_header('Authorization', 'GoogleLogin auth=' + auth)
        push_request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        push_request.add_header('Content-Length', len(data))
        urllib2.build_opener().open(push_request)

    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        print 'got exception during push notification'
        print 'Reason: "{0}" code: {1}'.format(e.reason, e.code)

        pass
```

this give me error: "Reason: "Unauthorized" code: 401" (at some point it was 403). Version which uses *httplib.HTTPSConnection* instead of *urllib2.Request* has same problem.

It looks almost the same as [code shown here](https://github.com/patrickbaumann/c2dmprototype/blob/master/pushprototypedjango/push/views.py#L93) so I'm totally confused. What I'm doing wrong?

---

**Edit:**

Just in case, here is how I fetch authorization token (it looks like that it works fine), maybe my parsing is wrong:

```
def getNewAndroidAuthorizationToken() :
    request = urllib2.Request("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin")

    data  = urllib.urlencode({'accountType' : 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',
                              'Email'       : 'someaccount@gmail.com',
                              'Passwd'      : 'asdjsdfa',
                              'service'     : 'ac2dm',
                              'source'      : 'com.mycompany.mypackage',})
    request.add_data(data)

    content = urllib2.build_opener().open(request)

    lines = content.readlines()
    for line in lines :
        if line.find("Auth=")==0 :
            return line[5:]
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C2DM` is deprecated. Developers are encouraged to switch to `GCM, C2DM` will be supported for a short time. Simple API instead of `ClientLogin` and `oAuth2` which are not supported.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html